# How to update a MYSQL table column from Varchar data type to a time

Tags: mysql, database, time, varchar, str-to-date

I have a table in an MYSQL database and one of the columns (Incident_Time) has values such as 03:15 A and 12:30 P stored as varchar data type. However, I would like to change the data type from varchar to timestamp (time) so that the values can be treated as time values. For example,time as 10:37 AM.

```
-------------
Incident_Time
--------------
| 10:37 A    |
| 03:15 A    |
| 12:20 P    |
```

I tried the following code:

```
UPDATE incident_tab_22 
SET Incident_Time = str_to_date(Incident_Time, '%h:%i  %p');
```

I keep getting the following error reading:

> Error 1411 (HY000): Incorrect datetime value: ‘10:37 A’ for function str_to_date

As an alternative solution, I also tried:

```
select *, SELECT STR_TO_DATE(Incident_Time, '%h:%i %p') ; as Time_of_Incident from incident_tab_22;
```

This just resulted in a column created (Time_of_Incident) with all NULL values.
I would appreciate any assistance I can get with this problem. Thanks.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5 and #3.

Comment: You have an extra space before `%p` in the format string.

Comment: Your alternative solution isn't valid SQL syntax, you shouldn't get any result.

Comment: `%p` parses `AM/PM` and not `A/P` - this causes NULLs on the output. Moreover, shown value `12:20 P` claims that A/P marks are fake. So use `STR_TO_DATE(Incident_Time, '%H:%i')`. *I tried the following code* UPDATE makes no sense - this won't change the column datatype.

Comment: @Akina what do you mean fake?

Comment: @ysth I mean that it is not a part of value, it is redundand marker which simplifies the daypart distinguishing. Or backwardly, it acts as "parity bit" and allows to detect incorrect time values (see https://dbfiddle.uk/5uB1602n).

Comment: @Akina still no clue what you mean.  there are 24 different hours, numbered 1 through 12 (though not occurring in that order) and either AM or PM; neither part is redundant.  yes, if you specify invalid hours for the %h format, it will reject them; that's not related to %p (though %p does adjust *valid* %h hours)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use %p you need to add an M:

```
select *, 
    STR_TO_DATE(concat(Incident_Time,'M'), '%h:%i %p') as Time_of_Incident
from incident_tab_22
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QhRU_82c)

Comment: Thank you, @ysth. This provided a solution that I could work with. I appreciate your response. Thanks again.

Comment: The code produced NULL values with times that began with "00", such as 00:55 A and 00:47 A. I corrected this by using %H instead of %h. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: Having 00 and am/pm is weird, did it do what you expected for 00 PM?